# Error : an integer is required (got type tuple)

Tags: python, class, datetime, tuples

I am stuck to return age from birth date. What I want to do is to return exact age from inputed birth date with using class. My current code is :

```
from datetime import datetime, date

class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, birth_date):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.birth_date = birth_date

    def full_name(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.first_name, self.last_name)

    def age(self):
        return date.today() - date(self.birth_date)


std = Person("aaa", 'bbb', (1990, 10, 11))
print(std.age())
```

I have to also return full name from inputed first name and last name respectively but that was already done.
It would be really appreciated if it is explained in detail.

Comment: You need to pass a datetime object not (1990,10,11)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use:

```
def age(self):
    return date.today() - date(year=self.birth_date[0], month=self.birth_date[1], 
                                          day=self.birth_date[2])
```

and it should return you: `9890, 00:00:00`

---

If you want to compute age in years, the easiest way would be:

```
def age(self):
    from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
    return relativedelta(date.today(), date(year=self.birth_date[0], 
                                            month=self.birth_date[1], 
                                         day=self.birth_date[2])).years
```

and the above should return you: `27`

---

You can also do:

```
def age(self):
    from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
    age = relativedelta(date.today(), date(year=self.birth_date[0], 
                                      month=self.birth_date[1], 
                                      day=self.birth_date[2]))
    return str(age.years) + ' years, ' + str(age.days) + ' days'
```

and the above should return you: `27 years, 28 days`

Comment: Thank you for answering with three type of solution. I've learnt a lot from you.